# Terraform Conditional Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a template in my terraform config to which I write the values of a variable like this:

```
data "template_file" "config" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/${var.json_config}")}"

  vars {
    is_enabled = "${var.is_enabled}"
  }
}
```

Now `is_enabled` is a boolean string which is either set to `true` or `false`. Now based on if this is true or false I want to set another variable. In pseudocode it would look like this:

if is_enabled == true 
    path = /one/path/
else
    path = /another/path

I had a look at the [`conditional values`](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-8/#conditional) but it seems to be for bringing up resources. how would I use this to set a variable in a template file ?

Answer (score 5):

Templates uses the same interpolation syntax as all other strings in Terraform. [Documentation is available](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html)

So in your case it will look like this:

```
path = ${is_enabled ? "/one/path/" : "/another/path"}
```

Comment: should be `var.is_enabled`

Comment: @BMW actually no, as this is template, not Terraform resource.